# Why Does CSS not work after Custom Url

Tags: php, css, url

I have made a custom url. Whenever I use the normal directory like `/profile.php/` it works, although when I use just `profile/` my CSS does not load.

Is there anyway I can fix this? And why is it doing it.

I found a fix I wrote:

```
<style>
    <?php include './css/style.css'; ?>
</style>
```

Although why does it have to be like that?

Comment: How are you creating your custom URLs?

Comment: @D12L12 The console show any error?

Comment: RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?username=$1

Answer (score 0):

I think your URLs profile.php , example.php , etc. load the css and /profile/ directories do not load the CSS because your code is trying to load the CSS from the /profile/ folder. Try to include the css from the root directory like this

```
<?php
echo "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://yoursite.com/css/style.css' />";
?>
```